# How to build ffmpeg executable binary for Android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm struggling how to build an executable binary of ffmpeg for Android command. I need to extract audio from video files such as mp4.

I followed a tutorial here to build ffmpeg binary: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

I dont need *.so file to use in NDK but only an executable binary.

I tried to enable: `--enable-ffmpeg` in shell script build. It yielded a ffmpeg file too. Especially, the file size is small with around 2M. However, I am unable to use it in android execution as following:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/example/ffmpeg -i /sdcard/test.mp4  -vn -acodec copy /sdcard/test.aac");
```

The above executed very quickly and of course it didn't give any result.

I continued searching and found an example here: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

The ffmpeg binary in the project is nice, I can run some command with desired output. However, some conversions to mp3 format gets failed because probably it lacked libmp3lame when building. Specially, `ffmpeg` is heavier than mine quite much, it is about 15M. I don't know how they build the binayr.

I'm looking for is a proper guide which I can build with arbitrary options such as `libmp3lame`, `libshine`. I get stuck at `m4a` to `mp3` conversion.

Comment: use ffmpeg libary instead of binary

Comment: the link contains virus please remove such links from this site.